# How to connect use INSERT query using SELECT query in mySQL

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have 2 tables, **cce_sa_fa** & **cce_activity**

I used the following line to get the *cce_sa_fa* not included in *cce_activity*

```
select id from cce_sa_fa where id NOT IN (select safa from cce_activity)
```

Using this query, I got 113 rows. Now I need to INSERT these ids into *cce_activity*. Here the id needs to be inserted and other columns are with fixed value. Usual insert query for cce_activity is as follows.

```
INSERT INTO `cce_activity` (`id`, `safa`, `name`, `mark`) VALUES (NULL, '"+id_of_ cce_sa_fa+"', 'Activity 1', '0');
```

How can I insert all the ids from the SELECT query to INSERT into **cce_activity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if columns same:

```
INSERT INTO cce_activity select * from cce_sa_fa where id NOT IN (select safa from cce_activity)
```

if not, something like:

```
INSERT INTO cce_activity (col1, col2, col3) select col1, col2, col3 from cce_sa_fa where id NOT IN (select safa from cce_activity)
```